# Get text of selected radio button, android?

Tags: android, radio-button, tablelayout

I have made 3X2 radio button programmatically.

This is my tableLayout

```
    public class ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout extends TableLayout implements
    OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout";
private RadioButton activeRadioButton;

/**
 * @param context
 */
public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
    if (activeRadioButton != null) {
        activeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    rb.setChecked(true);
    activeRadioButton = rb;

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.TableLayout#addView(android.view.View, int,
 * android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
 */
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index,
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    setChildrenOnClickListener((TableRow) child);
}


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.TableLayout#addView(android.view.View,
 * android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
 */
@Override
public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, params);
    setChildrenOnClickListener((TableRow) child);
}

private void setChildrenOnClickListener(TableRow tr) {
    final int c = tr.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        final View v = tr.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof RadioButton) {
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}

public int getCheckedRadioButtonId() {
    if (activeRadioButton != null) {
        return activeRadioButton.getId();
    }

    return -1;
}
 }
```

This is my main activity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainl);

    ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout    t=new ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(this);
    TableRow r1=new TableRow(this);
    TableRow r2=new TableRow(this);
    TableRow r3=new TableRow(this);
    b1=new RadioButton(this);
    b2=new RadioButton(this);
    b3=new RadioButton(this);
    b4=new RadioButton(this);
    b5=new RadioButton(this);
    b6=new RadioButton(this);
    b7=new RadioButton(this);
    b1.setText("b1");
    b2.setText("b2");
    b3.setText("b3");
    b4.setText("b4");
    b5.setText("b5");
    b6.setText("b6");
    b7.setText("b7");

    r1.addView(b1);
    r1.addView(b2);
    r1.addView(b3);
    r2.addView(b4);
    r2.addView(b5);
    r2.addView(b6);
    r3.addView(b7);
    t.addView(r1);
    t.addView(r2);
    t.addView(r3);
    l.addView(t);
            t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        Log.e("msg   ",     rb.getText().toString());
        Log.e("msg   ",     "clciked");

        }
    });
   }
```

I need to do these two following things

1. How do I find the text of radio button selected on main activity.
2. How do I make a one radio button selected by default on the start of activity and also it should remain mutually exclusive.

Comment: did you try r1.getText() for radio button's text? for setting default use r1.setChecked(true)

Comment: How about `getText()`

Comment: @Saqib If i use r1.setChecked(true) it makes it checked forever which is not needed.

Comment: you said how to set it checked at start, so this is how you do it

Comment: @user2310289 I used it but doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Saqib It should also be mutually exclusive

Comment: then on start of activity you have to uncheck all once and then select the desired one checked

Comment: @user2310289 I know about radiogroup. If you may please give me an example of how to create a 3x3 radiogroup with 9 radiobuttons

Comment: you doesn't seem to add your radio buttons in your toggleButtonGroupLayout did you?

Answer (score 1):

To find the text of radio button  use radiobutton.getText() method
To make one radio button selected by default for that in the xml make setChecked true for that radio button

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButton radioButton;
ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout toggleButtonGroupTableLayout;
Button buttonGet;

 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  toggleButtonGroupTableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tableR);
buttonGet = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonNext)
buttonGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int selectedId = toggleButtonGroupTableLayout.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(selectedId);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected: " + radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


     });
}
```